# Clients get IP from wrong subnet

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a Windows 2008 R2 Server with a DHCP server that manages a public IP net and a internal IP net. We use the latter for machine computers that are not supposed to show in the network and have restricted internet access.

All clients are supposed to get IPs from the public IP range. However, for a few weeks now, clients often get an IP from the private IP range (where they don't have network or internet access because they are not defined that way). The workaround that I tell my users is to try `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` until they got the correct IP. I also tried `ipconfig /registerdns` on the clients, but they keep getting the wrong IP.

As far as I know, nothing changed on the server. It is possible that this behaviour started with a round of Windows updates.

How do I get client PCs to alway grab the correct IP? Is it a DHCP or a client problem?

Disclaimer: I do administrate the server, but I basically inherited the duty and I am a complete newbie. I can manage users and register new clients, but that's about it.

Comment: Are they getting the leases _from the correct server_? This is pretty much what happens if someone connects a second DHCP server (e.g. the wrong end of a SOHO router) to the same network.

Comment: @grawity Yes. The private subnet should only be leased to static IPs that are connected to the MAC address of the clients in question. It did work like that in the past.

Comment: Does the wrong lease show up on the Win2008 "DHCP server" configuration? Does it have the same client ID, etc.?

Comment: @grawity I need to check that the next time the problem occurs. Will report back.

Comment: I think it would be useful to check the same from the client side, i.e. get a Wireshark packet capture of the actual DHCP leases/renews happening.

Comment: ipconfig /all should show you DHCP server IP which would confirm if you have a rogue one. We need more info on your subnet and/or physical network info to understand why this is happening. Maybe someone connected a patch cable on a switch incorrectly & bridged those separate networks together?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that one of two things is happening:

1. Your DHCP server has two different NICs, one for Public and one for private, and is not filtering the DHCP requests based on the NIC it is receiving them from. In this case, you'll need to configure the DHCP server to restrict traffic for the particular network.
2. Your network has multiple 'DHCP helpers' configured and is confusing the DHCP server and/or clients. DHCP traffic works by broadcast and as such cannot work normally when the DHCP server is on a different subnet from the client. To resolve this issue, the networking equipment can implement a "DHCP helper" which forwards the DHCP request broadcast from one network to the IP of the DHCP server (converts a broadcast to a unicast so it is routable). Make sure that you don't have multiple conflicting DHCP helpers on a single network or DHCP helpers on a network that should not have them.

Another workaround would be to restrict who can receive DHCP leases on the private network. 802.1x authentication or MAC filtering would prevent 'unauthorized' systems from receiving a DHCP lease on that scope.